# Pandas replace type issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a row that contains data such as:

```
1 year
1 month
1 week
4 year
3 week
```

etc etc

I am trying to replace anything that contains "month" or "week" to 0

```
train_df.age["weeks" in train_df.age] = 0
```

and

```
for i in train_df['age']:
    if "weeks" in i:
        i = "0"
```

None of which seem to work.

Any advice on how to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you expect this to look like?

Comment: are these two separate columns? or one column with a int and str?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the strings "month" or "week" to 0, or the numbers in the same rows in the other column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `str.contains`:

```
train_df.loc[train_df['age'].str.contains(r'week|month'), 'age'] = 0
```

Here we pass a regex pattern that looks for whether the row contains either 'week' or 'month' and use the boolean mask to selectively update just the rows on interest:

```
In [4]:
df.loc[df['age'].str.contains(r'week|month'), 'age'] = 0
df

Out[4]:
    age
1  year
1     0
1     0
4  year
3     0
```

Comment: Any idea, if this can be generalised to not just searching in the column 'age' but to replace week | month with 0 through the entire dataframe (so all columns)

Comment: @Vipluv you either stack the entire df and then unstack: `stacked = train_df.stack() stacked.loc[stacked.str.contains(r'week|month'), 'age'] = 0` and then call `unstack()` `unstack = stacked.unstack()` or you can just call apply on the df to generate a boolean mask and then replace `mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'week|week'))` and then do `df[mask] = 0`

Comment: the `mask` idea is actually working if i use `lambda x: str('week') in str(x)` as i have a df with mixed dtypes. otherwise with regex mask method as above i get  `error : nothing to repeat` ... maybe i will post a dedicated question about this with full examples

Comment: I elaborated the question a bit more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524343/replace-unwanted-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-element-wise-and-efficiently