# Replace unwanted strings in pandas dataframe element wise and efficiently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large dataframe (thousands x thousands) only showing 5 x 3 here, time is the index

```
                                  col1                col2             col3
time                                                                         
05/04/2018 05:14:52 AM             +unend           +unend                  0
05/04/2018 05:14:57 AM                 0                 0                  0
05/04/2018 05:15:02 AM            30.691             0.000              0.121
05/04/2018 05:15:07 AM            30.691             n. def.            0.108
05/04/2018 05:15:12 AM            30.715             0.000              0.105
```

As these are coming from some other device (df is produced by `pd.read_csv(filename)`) the dataframe instead of being a completely `float` type now ends up having unwanted strings like `+unend` and `n. def.`. These are not the classical `+infinity` or `NaN` , that `df.fillna()` could take care off. I would like to replace the strings with `0.0`. I saw these answers  [Pandas replace type issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37666731/pandas-replace-type-issue/37666756?noredirect=1#comment88037610_37666756) and  [replace string in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702338/replace-string-in-pandas-dataframe) which although try to do the same thing, are column or row wise, but not elementwise. However, in the comments there were some good hints of proceeding for general case as well.

If i try to do

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'+unend|n. def.'))
df[mask] =0.0
```

i get `error: nothing to repeat`

if i do

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x: (str('n. def.') in (str(x)) or (str('unend') in str(x))) )
df[mask]=0.0
```

i would get a Series object with True or False for every column rather than a elementwise mask and therefore an error
 `TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value`.

The below

```
mask = df.applymap(lambda x: (str('n. def.') in (str(x)) or (str('unend') in str(x))) )
df[mask.values]=0.0
```

does give me the intended result replacing all the unwanted strings with 0.0 However, it is slow (unpythonic?) and also, i am not sure if i can use regex  for the check rather than `in`, especially, if i know there are mixed datatypes. Is there an efficient, fast, robust but also elementwise  general way to do this?

Comment: In this case why not just convert it to numeric? `df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed [`Edchum`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524343/replace-unwanted-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-element-wise-and-efficiently/50524407#comment88060623_50524343) if need replace all non numeric values to `0` - first [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` create `NaN`s for not parseable values and then convert them to `0` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).fillna(0)
```

---

If values are not `substring`s use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) or very nice answer of [Haleemur Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50524584/2901002):

```
df = df.mask(df.isin(['+unend','n. def.']), 0).astype(float)
```

For `substrings` with define values:

There are special regex char `+` and `.`, so need escape them by `\`:

```
df = df.mask(df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(r'(\+unend|n\. def\.)')), 0).astype(float)
```

Or use [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elemnetwise check:

```
df = df.mask(df.applymap(lambda x: (str('n. def.') in (str(x)) or (str('unend') in str(x))) ), 0).astype(float)
```

---

```
print (df)
                          col1  col2   col3
time                                       
05/04/2018 05:14:52 AM   0.000   0.0  0.000
05/04/2018 05:14:57 AM   0.000   0.0  0.000
05/04/2018 05:15:02 AM  30.691   0.0  0.121
05/04/2018 05:15:07 AM  30.691   0.0  0.108
05/04/2018 05:15:12 AM  30.715   0.0  0.105
```

Answer (score 5):

> These are not the classical +infinity or NaN , that df.fillna() could take care off

You can specify a list of strings to consider as `NA` when reading the csv file.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, na_values=['+unend', 'n. def.'])
```

And then fill the `NA` values with `fillna`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, if na_values are well defined strings. Reading the data correctly avoids the expense of replace / convert later.

Comment: yes, this is actually a great answer ... and so much faster

Comment: @jpp - it depends, if values are substrings, it is not possible use :(

Comment: @Vipluv - but if strings, it is better.

Comment: @jezrael i agree to your point-- for very general uses (i.e df conversion once it is already there ) if you already have a dataframe and dont have control on when you are reading it in the accepted answer allows to do so

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use pd.Series.str.contains or pd.Series.isin**

A more efficient solution to this problem is to use `pd.to_numeric` to convert try and convert all data to numeric.

Use `errors='coerce'` to default to `NaN`, which you can then use with `pd.Series.fillna`.

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```